# AngularJS - Pushing JSON data (structure correct, but something missing)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm completely new to AngularJS and I'm converting a small app at the moment, although there's one thing tripping me up.

My goal is to add a module to the dashboard and everything works correctly if I hardcode the JSON data, although, it seems to be having issues when using a variable.

My service:

```
var pushData = angular.toJson({"modID": "mod_rText_01", "sequence": 1, "group": 1, "dashboard": 1, "type": "text", "content": ["17%", "operating capacity"]});
console.log(' :: Module data pushed: ' + pushData);
$rootScope.$broadcast('locations', pushData); // broadcast to controller
```

My controller:

```
// listen for service location updates
$scope.$on('locations', function(event, pushData) {
    console.log(' :: Module data received: ' + pushData);
    $scope.locations.push(pushData);
});
```

Console logs:

```
:: Module data pushed: {"modID":"mod_rText_01","sequence":1,"group":1,"dashboard":1,"type":"text","content":["17%","operating capacity"]}
:: Module data received: {"modID":"mod_rText_01","sequence":1,"group":1,"dashboard":1,"type":"text","content":["17%","operating capacity"]}
```

As mentioned, if I change the controller line to be:      `$scope.locations.push({"modID":"mod_rText_01","sequence":1,"group":1,"dashboard":1,"type":"text","content":["17%","operating capacity"]});`

It works correctly. I feel I'm missing something! Although, according to the console.log, the variable 'pushData' is correct, but nothing happens.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you transform your object to JSON.

What you are doing here is you actually send a `STRING`, not an object.

`angular.toJson({"modID": "mod_rText_01", "sequence": 1, "group": 1, "dashboard": 1, "type": "text", "content": ["17%", "operating capacity"]});`

This string is being published in event and picked up in controller. So in below code, instead of an object, you are really adding a string to an array:

`$scope.locations.push(pushData);`

**Solution:** just publish regular JavaScript object instead of string and it should work as expected. `$broadcast() and $on()` are capable to work with real objects as well.

```
var dataObj = {"modID": "mod_rText_01", "sequence": 1, "group": 1, "dashboard": 1, "type": "text", "content": ["17%", "operating capacity"]};
$rootScope.$broadcast('locations', dataObj);
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much. Seems I was overcomplicating things. Thanks for the quick reply too, all working. :)

Comment: One more thing - I usually use events just for the communication between controllers. If you want to implement regular controller+service scheme, then you would be better off with declaring dependency to the service inside your controller. And make explicit calls from there.